# Find the inverse linear transformation of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

**Question:** Let $T: R^2$ -> $R^2$  be an invertible linear transformation and suppose that $T[1, 2] = [1, 0] $ and $T[1, -2] = [0, 1]$. **Find** $T^{-1}[1, 2]$.

Note: [x, y] in the question represents a column matrix with x on the top and y on the bottom. I'm not sure how to format matrices here.

At first, I treated this problem as a matrix inversion problem and got [1, 2]. But I soon realized that this is incorrect. Could someone please explain to me how this works? I couldn't seem to locate any examples online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The inverse of a linear transformation is a linear transformation. So $T^{-1}[1,2]=T^{-1}[1,0]+2T^{-1}[0,1]$...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would $T$ be in this case though?

Comment: Ah I just got it! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Since $T$ is invertible, we have
$$T^{-1} \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right] \text{  and  } T^{-1}\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]= \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -2 \end{array} \right].$$
Can you take it from here?